# Builtin search panel disable whole grid with search panel. 2 more questions

Tags: jqgrid

1 - Is it possible to change the layout of Add and Edit popups?

2 - How to disable navigation in the Edit popup?. Right and left buttons to navigate through records.

3 - I am testing JQGrid built in search. Problem is when ever I click on that small search icon
popup disable whole grid with it search panel on top of it. Tried alot but no success.
***Note: All the other panels like Edit, Add etc are working fine***

```
jQuery().ready(function () {

    jQuery("#list10").jqGrid({
        //url: 'server.php?q=2',
        data: mydata1,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
            { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90 },
            { name: 'name', index: 'name asc, invdate', width: 100 },
            { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
        ],

        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager10',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "JSON Example"
    });
    jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager10', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }); 
});


                 var mydata1 = [
  { id: "1", invdate: "2010-05-24", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "2111.00" },
  { id: "2", invdate: "2010-05-25", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "21.00", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "12", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "13", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "15", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "16", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked many questions at once. So one after other.

1. You don't described what you mean under "the layout of Add and Edit popups". All standard settings of the dialogs like position, width, height and so on you can find [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties). All other dynamic changes of layout you can do inside of `beforeShowForm` event handler which you could define.
2. The easiest way to disable navidation buttons is to include `.navButton { display:none; }` in you CSS.
3. Parameters of the search dialog you can find [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options). The setting `overlay:false` should help you.

So you can replace the line

```
jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager10', {edit:false, add:false, del:false});
```

with something like following

```
jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager10',
                         {edit:false, add:false, del:false},
                         {top:200,left:300,recreateForm:true}, // edit settings
                         {top:100,left:200,recreateForm:true}, // add settings
                         {overlay:false} // search settings
);
```