# Possible jQuery/jqGrid problem in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jqgrid

I have a grid constructed with `jqGrid`, that uses the search toolbar, a custom formatter to insert `radio` boxes and a `loadComplete` handler. 
Everything works fine in FF but when I go to IE8 (shame!!!) the screen would freeze with the data loaded and the `Loading...` box on the screen. I can do nothing on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
function loadCompleteHandler(){
 jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('setGridHeight', Math.min(300,parseInt(jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-btable").css('height'))));
}

 function radio(value, options, rowObject){
  var radio = '<input type="radio" value=' + value + ' name="radioid" ondblclick="inDetail();"/>';
  return radio;
 }

 function statusSelect(){
  #set($select = ":$l10n.lbl_123")
  #foreach($se in $status_list) 
   #set($select = $select + ";$se.getValue():$se.getValue()") 
  #end  
  return "$select";
 }

 jQuery(function(){  
  jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
     url: '$content.getURI("/servlet/ajax/MyServlet.json")' + '?loggedUserId=$loggedUserId&pageNo=0&locale=' + '$l10n.getLocale().toString()',
     datatype: 'json',
     mtype: 'POST',
     colNames:['','$l10n.lbl_copy','$l10n.lbl_476','$l10n.lbl_380', '$l10n.lbl_2547<br/>$l10n.lbl_3768','$l10n.lbl_owner','$l10n.lbl_256 $l10n.lbl_92','$l10n.lbl_1558<br>$l10n.lbl_185','$l10n.lbl_348'],
     colModel :[ 
        {name:'column1', index:'column1', width:'3%', search:false, align:'center', formatter: radio, editable:false, sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'column2', index:'column2', width:'6%', search:false, align:'center', formatter:'checkbox', sortable: false, resizable:false}, 
        {name:'column3', index:'column3', width:'12%', sortable: false, stype:'select', editoptions:{value: statusSelect()}, resizable:false}, 
        {name:'column4', index:'column4', width:'17%', search:false, sortable: false, resizable:false}, 
        {name:'column5', index:'column5', width:'10%', search:false, sortable: false, resizable:false}, 
        {name:'column6', index:'column6', width:'13%', sortable: false, resizable:false}, 
        {name:'column7', index:'column7', width:'13%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
     {name:'column8', index:'column8', width:'12%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
     {name:'column9', index:'column9', width:'14%', sortable: false, resizable:false}
      ],
     width:'768',
  height: 300,
  loadonce:true,
  pager: '#pagerDiv',
  gridview: true,
  rowNum:15,
  rowTotal: 500,
     sortorder: 'desc',
     viewrecords: true,
  loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler
    }); 
 });

 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
       stringResult: true, 
       searchOnEnter: false, 
       defaultSearch:'cn'}); /* search strategy meaning: contains */
 });
```

I am using Velocity, jQuery 1.4.2. IE gives an invalid argument error in the jQuery library 
at this line:

```
 if ( set ) {
   style[ name ] = value;
  }
```

Maybe the problem is with jQuery in IE8, I don't know....

**EDIT** : more specific data added

I am using jqGrid 3.8.2. 
The `statusSelect` after Velocity has processed it looks like this:

```
function statusSelect(){
     return ":All;status1:status1;status2:status2";
}
```

I think there is no problem with the JSON data transfer since the grid previously worked in IE8 when there was no `setGridHeight`, `loadComplete` handler. I have also done some minor modifications which I can only partially recount (i.e. column resize disabled).
For testing purposes here is a JSON object:

```
    {
    "page":"1",
    "records":2,
    "rows":[{"id":150,"cell":[150,false,"status1","columnData4","columndata5","columndata6","columndata7","Test1\u003cbr/\u003e\u003cspan style\u003d\u0027float:right;\u0027\u003e10.12.2010\u003c/span\u003e","columnData"]},
      {"id":157,"cell":[157,false,"status2","columnData41","columndata51","columnData61","columnData71","Test2\u003cbr/\u003e\u003cspan style\u003d\u0027float:right;\u0027\u003e22.12.2010\u003c/span\u003e","columnData"]}],
    "total":50.0
    }
```

I don't know how to use the total parameter, so I just declared an arbitrary value (50D).
The inDetail function just submits the form (I am using Apache Turbine parameter here):

```
    function inDetail(){
        document.forms['myForm'].eventSubmit_doAction.value = 'doSomeAction';
        document.forms['myForm'].submit();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post how the function `statusSelect` looks like on the client side (after all #...)? Test JSON data could be also helpful to reproduce your problem. Which version of jqGrid you use? If you don't use a complex HTML code you could post it also.

Comment: Could you also post the code of `inDetail` function. The best is the full code which can be used to reproduce the problem. If you post JSON data, then one could reproduce the problem without having the server code.

Comment: I have added everything you've asked for. Hope this helps!

Comment: OK I will try to reproduce your problem. One more question: are you suer that you have comma before the last '}' in the JSON data: `"total":50.0,}` is a wrong JSON.

Comment: No comma. It probably appeared during the copy/paste. I corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce the problem which you describe. How you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Atticus.htm) the grid can be loaded without any problem in IE. It looks not fine because of missing CSSs, but all works in general. So I suppose you have problem in the code which you not publish here. I recommend you to verify your HTML page in http://validator.w3.org/, your test JSON results in http://www.jsonlint.com/ and JavaScript code in http://www.jslint.com/.

I would only not recommend you to use `radio` variable inside of the function with the same name `radio`. Better to choose another name. It is better also to add 10 as the second parameter of the `parseInt` function. In my tests your original code worked also without the corresponding code changes.

Comment: AFAIK the jqGrid should work with the jquery.jqGrid.min.js included. There is no need to include the javascripts from the src directory. If I comment the lines 15 through 23 (scripts from the src dicr) in your published example and uncomment line 25 the same problem appears.

Comment: @Atticus: In my environment the grid work without any problem also with compressed version of jqGrid (see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AtticusRel.htm). Verify which modules you can missing in your version of jquery.jqGrid.min.js (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477926/uncaught-exception-jqgrid-no-such-method-navgrid/4478136#4478136 for details)

Comment: @Oleg: thanks for the answer, I think the jQuery version caused the problem, because your examples use version 1.4.4 and when I changed it back to my 1.4.2 then it caused the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Atticus: You welcome, but I suppose, that your problem is somewhere else in the code which you not publish here. How you can verify http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AtticusRel142.htm the same code work without errors also with jQuery 1.4.2. If your original test page is accessible from the internet you can post the URL. If not you can try to use Developer (uncompressed) Version of jqGrid like in my first example and start the code in debugger from the IE Developer Tools (F12).

Comment: @Oleg: the interesting thing is that when I download your source and change the URL to my servlet and mtype to POST, my servlet does not get called in FF, and in IE it gets called, but it freezes like I mentioned in the question. This is interesting, since the only thing I change in your code is the servlet url and the mtype to POST. I am wokring to get to know what is happening here.

Comment: @Atticus: I wish you happy debugging! After you will find out the reason, please post it here: it's interesting for me. It you will need my help you could of course post here addition information also.