# radio button column mutually exclusive within all grid rows for this radio column using JqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid

How to create a grid with one special column of radio buttons in such a way if user click on this column of a particular row then only this radio button gets selected like if there is a radio group spread across this column of grid vertically  ??

I am looking for this solution in JqGrid (jquery) specifically .

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correct you can just use custom formatter. If all the buttons which you included has the same `name` attribute you will have the behavior which you need

```
formatter: function (cellValue, option) {
    return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" />';
}
```

After creating the column with radio buttons you will receive many other questions how to synchronize other functionality of jqGrid with the radio buttons. In the following example I show you how you can check the radio button on selecting the row:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var radio = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]');
    radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
    return true; // allow row selection
}
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWidthRadioButton.htm).

Comment: I want to do this way http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AtticusRel.htm also your creation I guess . i.e clicking the row do not automatically selects the radio button unless clicked over radio column . will be gr8 if you can explain code for that example aswell . Thanks.

Comment: @jason bourne: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Atticus.htm) is from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625152/possible-jquery-jqgrid-problem-in-ie8/4625703#4625703). It's just the original code (from the question), which works. The question was the "problem in IE8", but in my tests the grid contain was filled without any problems in IE.

Comment: I am struggling to send that value to my server to save it ?? how can I send that value to server ? thankx.

Comment: @jason bourne: When you want send the value? At the time at the radio button are clicked? Or at the time as the radio button are doubleclicked? Or you have somewhere an form with the button (for example the grid in inside of the form) and you want to send on click on the button? Do you want use "Submit" button so that the page should be reloaded of you want send the data per Ajax? I can continue with the questions. You should just describe more clear in what environment you use it. In general everything is possible you should just define what you need.

Comment: I just want when someone single clicks the radio button I can access whole rowObject inside some handler function . Thanks.

Comment: @jason bourne: Which `datatype` has the grid? Do you use `loadonce:true`? So the question is: has the grid *local* unformatted data of you can use only formatted data from the row? The method `getRowData` for example use unformatter for every column to get the data from which represent the row. The data can be not identical to what you send initially to the grid. What kind of `rowObject` you need to have?