# jqGrid Radio Button select single row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have JqGrid with RadioButton per each row like this.

```
  ...
 { name: 'select', label: 'select', width: 50, formatter:radio}
```

and function for radio formatter:

```
function radio(value, options, rowObject){
   var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" value=' + value + ' name="radioid" />';
   return radioHtml;
}
```

when I try to select a singlerow  from the jqgrid i.ee., radio button which is only selected using this function:

```
  $(function () {
   $("#<%=editButton.ClientID%>").click(function () {
       var ids = $("#table").jqGrid('getCol', 'select', true);
       alert(ids)
       for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
           //alert(ids[i].id)
           if (ids[i].id != '') {
               var idx = $("#table").jqGrid('getCell', ids[i].id, 'select');
           }
          // alert(idx);
       }
   });
 });
```

Am getting all the rows available in the grid rather than single selected row.

The same function works well if formatter is checkbox but not for radio. Is there something  missing?

UPDATE:

```
   colModel: [
                     { name: 'select', label: 'select', width: 50,
                         formatter: function radio(cellValue, option) {
                             return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid +       '"  />';
                         } 
                     },
                     { name: 'code', label: 'Branch Code', width: 250 },
                     { name: 'name', label: 'Branch Name', width: 250 },
                     { name: 'status', label: 'Group Status', width: 250 },
                ],
```

Function Click Handler:

```
     $("#<%=editButton.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            alert('M');
            var $selRadio = $('input[name=radio_' + $table[0].id + ']:checked'), $tr;
            alert('I');
            if ($selRadio.length > 0) {
                $tr = $selRadio.closest('tr');
                if ($tr.length > 0) {
                    alert("The id of selected radio button is " + $tr.attr('id'));
                }
            } else {
                alert("The radio button is not selected");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your current code from `$("#<%=editButton.ClientID%>").click` is too complex. You can do what you need in more simple way.

First of all I recommend you to use the `name` attribute of the `<radio>` button which is depend on the id of the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401729/315935)). It could be like the following

```
formatter: function (cellValue, option) {
    return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '"  />';
}
```

You can get the id of selected radio button with the following code

```
$("#<%=editButton.ClientID%>").button().click(function () {
    var $selRadio = $('input[name=radio_' + $grid[0].id + ']:checked'), $tr;
    if ($selRadio.length > 0) {
        $tr = $selRadio.closest('tr');
        if ($tr.length > 0) {
            alert("The id of selected radio button is " + $tr.attr('id'));
        }
    } else {
        alert("The radio button is not selected");
    }
});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWidthRadioButton1.htm) which demonstrate this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Oleg, No success  this line isnt executing var $selRadio = $('input[name=radio_' + $table[0].id + ']:checked'), $tr; where "table" is my grid id.

Comment: @Samuel: What you mean "this line isnt executing"? Is the click handle not be called or you get an exception in the line or the `$selRadio` returns always object with `length` = 0? Which `formatter` you used? Do you included `option.gid` in the `name` of radio button? You should compare exactly my demo with youth. Is my demo work in your environment? If it is work you should just find the difference to your code.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Have updated my Question with changes mentioned by you.. sorry for not describing the full error. The Code isnt executing after the mentioned line no exception,noundefined value. I mean I just placed a simple alert before and after the line.

Comment: @Samuel: It's unclear for me which element you bind with `$("#<%=editButton.ClientID%>")`. In my demo it's external button, because you don't describe what is it in your case. If `alert('M');` not works that you bind to wrong DOM element. You should examine the code in the web browser to see what code will be generated on the client side.

Comment: @Samuel: You are welcome! To get the value of the radio button you should first select the item. The code can be like for `$selRadio`. If you prefer another API which get you HTML fragment `var radioHtml = mygrid.jqGrid('getCell', $tr.attr('id'), 'select');` then you can get the jQuery object like `var $selRadio = $(radioHtml);`. In any way you can use `$selRadio.val()` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

add the column like this

```
{ 
    label:' ',
    name:' ',
    index:"id",
    width:20,
    search: false,
    formatter: function radio(cellValue, option,) {
        return '<input type="radio" value = '+cellValue+' name="radio"  />';
    } 
},

$('#buttonid').button().click(function () {
    var $selRadio = $('input[name=radio]:radio:checked'), $tr;

    if ($selRadio.length > 0) {
        $tr = $selRadio.closest('tr');

        if ($tr.length > 0) {              
            var grid = $("#jqGrid");
            var row = $tr.attr('id');
            var role_desc = grid.jqGrid('getCell', row, 'colname');
        }
    }
}
```

`jqGrid` is grid id, `colname` gives your column name its working me.....

Answer (score -1):

I needed a simpler solution so I came up with this way which uses the built-in multiselect rather than adding yet another col to the grid.

```
var gridSelector = $("#myGrid");

multiselect : true,
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e)
{
    $(gridSelector).jqGrid('resetSelection');
    return (true);
},
beforeRequest : function() {
    $('input[id=cb_myGrid]', 'div[id=jqgh_myGrid_cb]').remove();
},
loadComplete : function () {
    $('input[id^="jqg_myGrid_"]').attr("type", "radio");
},
```