# How to get the entire row value of Struts2 grid in action class

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I am using struts2 jquery grid. It has 2 formatters email & sms. It has a select with 2 options active or inactive. The user can change from active to inactive & vice versa. So basically i have to save both the columns value in the database.

```xml
<sjg:gridColumn name="eMail" index="eMail" 
                 title="Mail Alert" editable="true"
                 sortable="true" formatter="Mail"/>
```

formatter

```js
function Mail(value, options, rowObject){
    var option = {"Inactive": "Inactive","Active":"Active"};
    var radioHtml = '<select>';
    $.each(option, function(key, val){
        radioHtml+='<option value="'+key+'"'+(key==value?' selected="selected"':'')+'>'+val+'</option>';
    });
    radioHtml+='</select>';
    return radioHtml;
}
```

And same for sms.

Can anyone help me how to go about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8552853/1654265

Comment: tnxx Andrea for reply. But the problem is I am not specifing the user id to the value attribute of <select> (Because then the formatter will not work).

Comment: You can add the user id to the value of select, so the select option will be - Active-12345 or Inactive-12345 then at the server you can split it to find status and ID.

Comment: Thats a great idea. Thanks Alireza, I will give it a try.