# Attach onSelectRow event to jqGrid Formatter

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with Radio Button formatter for each row in the jqGrid. Everything works fine

My Cell Formatter for the RadioButton looks like this

```js
formatter: function radio(cellValue, option) {
    return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" value=' +
           cellValue + '/>';
}
```

Now am trying to attach `onSelectRow` event to this RadioButton formatter i.e.., When ever I click a Radio Button it should give me the Row Id Value. How can I do this? Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean under "it should give me the Row Id Value"? How you imagine the "giving"? The goal of the formatter to format the data only. So the formatter itself can't "give" something more as the string with HTML fragment used to construct the content of cell (`<td>` element). What you really need?

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I need  to get the rowId when I check on Radio button.

Comment: I asked you to explain *more detailed* what you mean. `onSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` for example *get* you the rowid. So please explain what you really need. For example, is your problem that you want to encapsulate the code of "onclick" on the button and `onSelectRow` in the code which is *separate* from the code of main grid? Probably an example of actions which you need to do on check of the radio button can explain all.

Comment: Sorry Oleg, Let me exlain this in detail. Have seen the function onSelectRow which gives me the rowId of clicked row. I need to achieve the same when I select/check the Radio Button in the jqgrid.Hope have made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeSelectRow` callback like

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input[type="radio"]')) {
        alert('The radio button are selected in the row with id=' + rowid);
    }
    return true; // allow row selection
}
```

to catch click event on the radio button. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWidthRadioButton2.htm).

You can additionally implement selection of the radio button if the user select the row somewhere (see the demo [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401729/315935)).