# AJAX JSON data is not display in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid now am trying to show data when click of one colmodel at the time i need to display data in another jqgrid i received data from server and it pass some function and shown data but it not display any data but no error too how to display in it??

```
gridland.jqGrid({

        datatype:'local',
        data: val,


        colNames:clnms,
        colModel:collmdls,
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: "land_details_table_pager",
        gridview:true,
        //rownumbers:true,
      //  sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        caption:"Land Detail",
        height: '100%',
        autowidth:true,
        shrinkToFit:false,



        onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) 
        {    



           var cm =  gridland.getGridParam('colModel');

            var rowData = gridland.getRowData(rowid);

            alert("rowData====>"+JSON.stringify(rowData));

            var slNno = rowData['slNno'];

             $("#currpattachk").val(rowid);

             var district;
             var taluk;
             var  village;
             var applId;

             $.each(val,function(k,v){

                 district= v.districtCode;
                 taluk=v.talukCode;
                 village=v.villageCode;
                 applId=v.applicationId;
           });
  if(cm[index].name == "pattaNo")
               {
                    alert("HERE pattaNo");





                   var pattaNo = rowData['pattaNo'];   // perticuler Column name of jqgrid that you want to access
                   var splitsursuvy=rowData['survsub'].split("/");




                  var arr= {}

                 arr.district= district;
                  arr.taluk=taluk;
                 arr.village=village;
                 arr.pattaNo=pattaNo
                arr.surveyno=splitsursuvy[0]  
                arr.subdivno=splitsursuvy[1];
                arr.applicationId=applId;


                var landarrchk=[];
                landarrchk.length=0;


             var inputVal=  JSON.stringify(arr);



                //alert("in fetch owners");
                //alert("inputval====>"+JSON.stringify(arr));
                //alert("inputVal===> "+inputVal);
                //var hash = cal_hmac(xx);
                //var m = "";
            //  document.getElementById('imgdiv').style.display = 'block';

                $.ajax({
                        url: urlService + serviceName + '/getsublanddetails?jsoncallback=?',
                        headers:
                        {
                            "emp_value": ses,
                            "signature": hash,
                            "roleId": roleId,
                            "timestamp": t,
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        data: inputVal.toString(),
                        // jsonpCallback:"aaa",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function(data)
                        {


                            var s_no=1;
                            content="";

                            var datachk;

                            /*var survsub;
                            =v.surveynewNo+"/"+v.subDivnewNo;*/

                            $.each(data, function(k, v)
                                    {
                                $.each(v.OwnerData, function(k, v1)
                                        {   

                                    datachk+='<div style="display:none"  id="currpatta'+s_no+'" >'+ JSON.stringify(v1) + '</div>'

                                    $("#landnewdetailchk").html(datachk);

                                    v1.survsub=v1.surveynewNo+"/"+v1.subDivnewNo;
                                    v1.slNno=s_no;
                                    v1.select='<input type="radio" name="subradio" id="subradio" onclick="getcurrpatta(' + s_no + ')" />';

                                    getsublanddetails(v1);


                                        });
                                s_no++;
                                    });

                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                        {
                            // alert("Error:"+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                            alert("Error Occured");
                            document.getElementById('imgdiv').style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        });


               }
});
}
```

second grid:

```
function getsublanddetails(arr)
{




    alert("Landdetailgrid======="+JSON.stringify(arr));


    clnms=['S.No','SurveyNo/SubDivisionNo','Excet Hect','Excet Hect','Select Subdivision'];

    collmdls=[


               {
                    name:'slNno',
                    index:'slNno',
                    classes:'slNno',
                    width:150,
                    align:'center',
                    sorttype: 'String'
                },

                {
                    name:'survsub',
                    index:'survsub',
                    classes:'survsub',
                    value:20,
                    width:150,
                    align:'center' 
                  //    onCellSelect:ff()   

                   },

                {
                    name:'Exthect',
                    index:'Exthect',
                    classes:'Exthect',
                    width:150,
                    align:'center',
                    sorttype: 'String'
                 }, 


                 {
                    name:'Extarea',
                    index:'Extarea',
                    classes:'Extarea',
                    width:150,
                    align:'center',
                    sorttype: 'String'
                  },

                  {
                        name:'select',
                        index:'select',
                        classes:'select',
                        width:150,
                        align:'center',
                        sorttype: 'String'
                      },
];
$("#landdetailnew").jqGrid({




        datatype:'local',
        data: arr,


        colNames:clnms,
        colModel:collmdls,
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: "landnewdetail",
        gridview:true,

        //rownumbers:true,
      //  sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        caption:"New Land Detail",
        height: '100%',
        autowidth:true,
        shrinkToFit:false
});



}
```

json data are:

```
Landdetailgrid======={"villageCode":"057","District_Code":"16","Extarea":12,"talukCode":"03","subDivnewNo":"2A","Exthect":0,"curpatta":1840,"surveynewNo":"167   ","survsub":"167   /2A","slNno":1,"select":"<input type=\"radio\" name=\"subradio\" id=\"subradio\" onclick=\"getcurrpatta(1)\" />"}

Landdetailgrid======={"villageCode":"057","District_Code":"16","Extarea":9,"talukCode":"03","subDivnewNo":"2B","Exthect":0,"curpatta":1841,"surveynewNo":"167   ","survsub":"167   /2B","slNno":1,"select":"<input type=\"radio\" name=\"subradio\" id=\"subradio\" onclick=\"getcurrpatta(1)\" />"}
```

Comment: close the `collmdls` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems in the code which you posted

1. The data displays after "Landdetailgrid=======" are **not array of items**.  You can't display one item of data. The data should have outer `[].
2. It seems that you tried to call `getsublanddetails` function **more as once**. The first call `$("#landdetailnew").jqGrid({...});` will convert the empty table `<table id="landdetailnew"></table>` in relative complex structure of divs and tables. So you can't do this more as once. What one can do is setting of new value of `data` option and reloading of jqGrid data using `$("#landdetailnew").trigger("reloadGrid");`. Alternatively one can use `$("#landdetailnew").jqGrid("GridUnload");` to *destroy grid* before creating another grid on the same place.
3. The input data for the column `'select'` seems have problems. It's OK to have **one element** on the page in the form, but if the grid would more as one row you will have **id duplicates** because all elements of the column will have the same `id="subradio"` attribute (`<input type="radio" name="subradio" id="subradio" onclick="getcurrpatta(1)" />`).
4. The general code of `onCellSelect` callback in the main grid seems too complex and can by reduced in multiple times. I would recommend you to use `datatype: "jsonp", loadonce: true` in the second grid. You can use `ajaxGridOptions: {headers: ...}` option to set additional HTTP headers of the request and you can use `jsonReader: {root: "OwnerData"}` to inform which part of the server response should be used as jqGrid data.
5. You can remove `onclick="getcurrpatta(1)"` part which you use in `select` column. You can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to place `<input type="radio" name="subradio"/>` data in the column. One can use `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` to process the `onclick` event in the radio button column.

Comment: thanks for helping on this data display good and work fine but except one that radio button i dono how to do this where to put ?? kindly help on this on this

Comment: @user3607180: You are welcome! Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7401729/315935) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935): `e.target` is the elements which was clicked in the grid you can test it like `$(e.target).is("input[type=radio")` or `$(e.target).is("input[name=subradio")`. You can use `iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0])` to get the index of the column and test `this.p.colModel[iCol].name === "select". So you can detect `onclick` using `beforeSelectRow`.